# Show JQuery qtip on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2, qtip

I have a list of elements with JQuery qtip attached to each and I would like the qtip to automatically show when user scrolls the page.

Please note that only the qtip for uppermost visible element on top of the page should be shown when scrolling.

I looked through the docs and came across http://qtip2.com/options#show.ready
but the problem with this is it cannot be used with scroll event.

```
 <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/3.0.3/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/3.0.3/jquery.qtip.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div>Sample link</div>
    <div>Sample link</div>
    <div>Sample link</div>
    <div>Sample link</div>
    <div>Sample link</div>
    <div>Sample link</div>
    <div>Sample link</div>
    <div>Sample link</div>
    <div>Sample link</div>

    <script>
        $('div').qtip({
            content: 'I use the built-in jQuery .slideUp() and .slideDown() methods',
            show: {
                effect: function () {
                    $(this).slideDown();
                },
            },
            hide: {
                effect: function () {
                    $(this).slideUp();
                }
            }
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        div {
            width: 100px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this:

```
    let divs = $('div');

    document.body.onscroll = function () {
        let div height = 200;
        let index = Math.floor(window.scrollY / div_height);
        let div = divs[index];
        if (div.classList.contains("active")) {
            return;
        }

        if (index > 0 && div.previousElementSibling.classList.contains("active")) div.previousElementSibling.classList.remove("active");
        if (index < divs.length && div.nextElementSibling.classList.contains("active")) div.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("active");

        div.classList.add("active")
        $(div).qtip("show")
    }
```